# Do you know which set these large grey ball and socket pieces belong to?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Does anyone know which set this piece belongs to:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top two pieces there (not the 2x2 square) are

**[Cylinder Hemisphere 2 x 2 Ball Turret Socket Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44358&idColor=86#T=S&C=86&O=%7B%22color%22:86,%22iconly%22:0%7D)**

[image: Cylinder Hemisphere 2 x 2 Ball Turret Socket Base]

and

**[Cylinder Hemisphere 3 x 3 Ball Turret](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44359&idColor=86#T=S&C=86&O=%7B%22color%22:86,%22iconly%22:0%7D)**

[image: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44359&idColor=86#T=S&C=86&O={"color":86,"iconly":0}]

The top appears in [28 sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=44359&in=S), the simplest of which is this [ion cannon](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75097-20)
[image]